# Calculating the statistically significant number of iterations

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, statistics, heuristics

Suppose I have a group of equations, whose distribution I want to see over a set of possible combination of coefficients:

```
f(x) = a.x^5 + b.x^4 + c.x^3 + d.x^2 + e.x^1
g(x) = p.x^5 + q.x^4 + r.x^3 + s.x^2 + t.x^1
```

That is the objective is to evaluate `f(x)` and `g(x)` keeping `x` fixed to some value.

All the coefficients: `a,b,c,d,e,p,q,r,s,t` can take values `0 or 1` at a time. Which means that there are `2^10` possible combinations of these coefficients.

So assume `x` is fixed and coefficients are denoted by `m=[a,b,c,d,e,p,q,r,s,t]`, the input vector and I can generate random inputs of this size within the bounds `(0 or 1)` by using the command

```
m = numpy.random.randint(2,size=10) # 2 means values lie 0 or 1; 10 is the length of vector generated
```

The point is it is not a practical way to generate `2^10` of such inputs, much worse if the number of coefficients increases.

So my question is that **what number of such inputs I should generate so that I can be sure of the nature of the distribution of function values?**

Is there any straight forward way to decide the number of inputs that reflects the function values closely as it would have if all the possible inputs were used to evaluate these functions?

**P.S I am not sure that this question falls within the domain of stackoverflow or not**

Comment: I can't understand well your question. On the one hand, `numpy.random.randint(2,5)` gives you a single integer in the range [2, 5), did you mean `numpy.random.randint(0, 2, (2,5))`? Second, you say `x=[a,...,t]`, but `x` is also the variable in `f` and `g`. For what value/s are the polynomials `f` and `g` evaluated? And what do you want to get exactly, something like the average evaluation value for all possible combinations of parameters (`a` to `t`)? It is hard to tell what exactly you want to compute.

Comment: @jdehesa I have made corrections.

Comment: I see, thanks. It's still hard to follow what you are trying to do. Are you considering `f(x)` and `g(x)` as random functions, and want to compute things like their expected value or their standard deviation, considering each coefficient, for example, a Bernoulli-distributed variable with p=0.5? If that is the case, wouldn't `f(x)` and `g(x)` be equivalent? Or otherwise, what is the probability distribution that you are considering? And what exactly you mean by "be sure of the nature of the distribution"?

Comment: @jdehesa I am just calculating the values of these functions independently for all possible combinations of coefficients. That's it. after that the distribution of all such values of functions can be observed. My concern is different. Since coefficients  can take values of either 0 or 1 so total such combinations of coefficients will be `2^10`. Now generating all inputs is not a practical solution so I want to know what is the minimum number of these input vector of coefficients that can give me a good approximation of all the possible input vectors of coefficients to calculate these functions